# Spring OAuth2 Authorization Server + Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-authorization-server

I'm trying to rewrite existing OAuth2 authorization service using `Spring Boot 3.0.2` and newly released `Spring OAuth2 Authorization Server 1.0.0`.
Faced a trouble combing objects from Reactive Security and Standard Security libraries: unable to apply default security to `OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration` class, because it's not applicable to reactive `ServerHttpSecurity`.

Code part

```
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public SecurityWebFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
    http
        .formLogin()
        ...;

    return http.build();
}
```

Can't pass `HttpSecurity` to `applyDefaultSecurity()` method.
Tried to find any reactive implementations of `OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration` class but found nothing.

Is there any way to convert `ServerHttpSecurity` to `HttpSecurity`? Or Spring OAuth2 Authorization Server is completely incompatible with reactive approach?

Main dependencies of Maven pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks is advance.

**UPD**

Searched badly. Seems like it's not supported yet:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/152

Or there are still some ways make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official answer:

> We are strictly focusing on a Servlet implementation for the initial set of features that would qualify for a MVP version. We haven't decided whether we'll provide a WebFlux version at this point.
>
> Quite honestly, I'm not convinced it's needed. The client and resource server(s) are the most active, whereas, the authorization server is not as active as it simply issues a token and may validate a token, which is limited activity between the many interactions that follow between a client and resource server after a token is issued.
>
> Either way, I'm going to close this issue as WebFlux is not on the roadmap as of now.

Source - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/152